# Moving imported photos to external drive

Tags: backup, photos, photos.app

I've been importing my DSLR photos using the standard `Photos.app`. Now I'm running out of HDD space. What's the best way to move my RAW photos to an external storage device?

Comment: are you able to search in Photos.app for all photos that are RAW formatted?  To do that you could just create a smart album from the File menu and select the "Text" condition to search for "RAW".  All the photos that show up after creating that search can be dragged to your external storage device.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an intuitive "grandma could do it" GUI solution, but I ended up doing:

```
find / -iregex '^.*\.cr2$' -exec zip cr2.zip {} \; -delete 2>/dev/null
```

Then used the GUI to click & drag the `.zip` archive to the external USB HDD, mounted at `/Volumes/disk2/`.

Looks like all the images imported directly from the DSLR are stored in `~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/`. So in hindsight; to target the specific directory, instead of searching the entire filesystem, I would input the relevant path:

```
find ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/ -iregex '^.*\.cr2$' -exec zip cr2.zip {} \; -delete 2>/dev/null
```

Or even better, eliminate the need to click and drag by including the destination path as well:

```
find ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/\
-iregex '^.*\.cr2$'\
-exec zip /Volumes/disk2/cr2.zip {} \;\
-delete 2>/dev/null
```

---

Or simply `mv` rather than `zip`:

```
find ~/Pictures/Photos\ Library.photoslibrary/Masters/\
-iregex '^.*\.cr2$'\
-exec mv {} \; /Volumes/disk2/ 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `-iname '*.cr2'` is probably sufficient (and quicker).